# Can I size an image so it can be printed at 5×7" but looks bad at sizes above that?

Tags: image-quality, resolution, prints

I generally try to print all images for clients and require that they purchase a print prior to the release of any "small sized file" for holiday cards, web-use, but a faux-pas in my new (app-based) contract has a client requesting an image she didn't "buy" for the above listed use.

1. I need to create a size that will work well for a holiday card and web, but not for reproducing to a print. What should my LR output be to achieve this, assuming the card would be no larger than a 5x7?
2. Is there a formula that one can use to determine this on varied sizes? ,Say, 8x10 looks good, but at 11x14, pixelation occurs?  5 x 7 looks good, 8x10 does not?

I've posted in FB forums, however, the response was, "Trust that your client won't print large!" Um, right.  This is the key image in the group and the only one that she selected yet didn't buy in 11 x 14.

Comment: I disagree with flagging this as a duplicate question because she's asking not just about pixels for print size, but also about restricting the size so that it can't be used larger.  There are a number of issues here that are not addressed in the other question with its 5 answers.

Comment: The other question (and each of the answers) is concerned with maximizing the quality of an image that will enable it to be printed at the largest size possible. This question is concerned with minimizing the quality of an image so that it is barely acceptable at a certain print size.

Comment: @JCDILL You can click the "reopen" button to support your contention.

Comment: @mattdm It was Deb that edited the commentary into the question, not JC DILL so there may be something we need to deal with here.

Comment: *gets more coffee*

Comment: Personally, I don't see any "number of issues here that aren't addressed". It seems like knowing about the thresholds for print quality at different sizes pretty much gives the answers to both parts of your question. Can you elaborate on you're still missing?

Comment: My apologies for any lack of clarity. I'm a novice on this site - and the plethora of information is both extensive and overwhelming. I'm still stymied, however. Using the chart, I can guess that a 5x7 should be 300ppi? at 3mp max? And if this is enlarged to 11  x 14, it will look bad, Yes? Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting is that what looks "good" to one person can look aweful to another.